# If $~\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} - 8x + b = \frac32~ $, find $~ a+b=~?$

Tags: limits

If $$~\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} - 8x + b = \frac32~ ,$$ find $~ a+b=~?$

I get $a-16b = 24$,
But how to get $a+b$?

a,b is positive integer

Comment: How do you got this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} - 8x + b = \frac32$

Define $k(x) \equiv 
\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} - 8x$

$k(x)= (\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} - 8x) \frac{\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} + 8x}{\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} + 8x}$
$$=\frac{64x^2 + ax + 7 - 64x^2}{\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} + 8x}$$
$$=\frac{a + \frac7x}{\sqrt{64 + \frac ax + \frac 7 {x^2}} + 8}$$

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}k(x) = \frac a {16}$

And by assumption, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} k(x) + b = \frac 3 2$, so 
$$\frac a {16} + b = \frac 3 2$$

This is a necessary and sufficient condition for the conditions stated, meaning there are many possible solutions. For example, setting $a = 0, b = \frac 3 2$ works and then $a + b = \frac 3 2$.

Comment: It could be b=0? a = 24?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Yes

Comment: is it ok in limit, that the constant b is neglected from the limit computation? is there any website i can read regarding this?

Comment: No that's not okay. I recommend you plug in various values into www.wolframalpha.com by typing something like "limit as x goes to infinity of sqrt{64x^2 + 0.111 x + 7} - 8x + 0.222" and seeing the result is 0.111/16 + 0.222. And then you can change the value of b to 0.223 and see that the answer changes to 0.111/16 + 0.223. This means the value of b is important to the final result.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} =\sqrt{(8x)^2 + ax + 7} =\sqrt{(8x)^2 + 2\times(?)\times(8x)+ 7} \\
$$note that $$2\times(?)\times(8x)=ax \to ?=\frac{a}{16}$$so

$$\sqrt{(8x)^2 + 2(\frac{a}{16})(8x)+ 7}=\sqrt{(8x+\frac{a}{16})^2 -(\frac{a}{16})^2+ 7}\\x\to \infty \sqrt{(8x+\frac{a}{16})^2 -(\frac{a}{16})^2+ 7}\sim |8x+\frac{a}{16}| $$ 
so 
$$lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{64x^2 + ax + 7} - 8x + b = \frac{3}{2}\\
lim_{x\to\infty}|8x+\frac{a}{16}| - 8x + b = \frac{3}{2}$$ now can you take over?

a,b are a positive integer so 
$$\frac{a}{16}+b=\frac{3}{2}\\b=0\to \frac{a}{16}+0=\frac{3}{2} \to a=24 \to a+b=24\\b=1 \to \frac{a}{16}+1=\frac{3}{2} \to a=8 \to a+b=1+8=9\\b=2,3,... impossible $$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: The question changed? anyway, you can't find $a+b$ with this only information, I guess there must be a bit more information on the original problem. Such as function graph or a point or asymptote...isn't there?

Comment: No... thats all the information. Except a and b is integer positive

Comment: I cant take over, pls help me

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: your question has a lack of information to find two variable. I think there is miss information.$$\frac{a}{16}+b=\frac{3}{2}$$